# Mac says password is wrong but it's right. I have to enter it twice to start Mac every time. How could I solve it?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos, password

Mac says password is wrong, but is right, and wants me to enter it again to start Mac every time. My password is used to be characters and numbers. I changed my password into all numbers but it doesn't work.

How could I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just checking: Are you talking about your user account password, or a firmware password?

Comment: Or is it a Firevault password?

Comment: Same issue here... I always have to type the password two times or type very slowly... otherwise some inputs are lost. This is definitely a bug and Apple is not doing anything :(

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the user password and you are locked out of your mac, you can try the following:

1. Reboot into the Recovery Drive by choosing the ‘Apple‘ menu > Restart, hold down the ‘command’ + ‘r’ keys on the keyboard during the start up process, when you see the start up screen you can let go. When the machine boots eventually you will see the macOS or OS X Utilities screen.
2. Go to the Utilites menu and select Terminal
3. At the prompt type ‘resetpassword’ (hit enter)
4. Reset your password

Keep in mind that this deletes your keychain, so your saved passwords are lost

Comment: From what the OP says it seems they can log in or boot up, but they have to enter the password twice.

Comment: Sorry, I have to apologize. I don't know why, it suddenly become normal. I don't know if it would happen again, but it seems good today. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. I found out when I watch what's happening carefully, as I type my password the first time the Mac resets and clears the text area (shortens the line of asterisks) and I have to enter it again - making sure it's not a partial entry. Seems something is still waking up in the background. Type slowly and observe if the line of '***' becomes suddenly shorter. Frustrating.

Other causes have to do with unlocking FileVault if you have that set up. Found on discussions.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you need to *wait* for the "Enter Password" text to appear in the input box.  If you begin typing sooner, those characters won't be captured.

Answer (score 0):

My mom typed her password wrong too many times, and the account just says it's locked.  It might have unlocked later by itself after a time (1 min, 5 min, 15 min, 1 hour https://support.apple.com/guide/security/passcodes-and-passwords-sec20230a10d/web), but I clicked the ? and reactivated the computer.  The activation server failed to respond a few times, but eventually it reactivated.  Then I went back and logged in with the old password, and all was good.  I was all set to make an apple genius bar appointment, but that appears to be disabled these days online.  You can also hold down power extra long on startup and get to recovery options.